# Stubbing controller actions in RSpec request specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am writing an API test case for server errors. I want to stub a controller action to raise an error to simulate the server error (500).
In the requests spec, the `controller` variable is not set.

```
it "Should return 500 upon server error" do
  controller.stub(:index).and_raise(ArgumentError) 
  get "/users.json"
  response.code.should eq("500")
end
```

Comment: a request spec for a controller spec?

Comment: I think @apneadiving is right, that makes no sense as a controller test. You are stubbing the whole method you are supposed to test.

Comment: @apneadiving My API test specs are implemented as request specs and almost all the test cases are true request specs. Only one case is hybrid as I need to check the error code upon server error. I need stubbing as I can't trigger a server error. Is there any other ways to test this (other than using controller spec)

Comment: I don't see any clean workaround, neither don't I see any reason not to split specs.

Comment: @apneadiving I have to maintain an extra spec file for one test case. (I wanted to avoid it if possible).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up stubbing the controller method using `any_instance`.

```
it "Should return 500 upon server error" do
  UsersController.any_instance.stub(:index).and_raise(ArgumentError)
  get "/users.json"
  response.code.should eq("500")
  response.body.should have_json_path("error")
end
```

**Note:**

Stubbing controller methods in a request spec doesn't make sense. But... In this case I am using the request spec suite as the acceptance criteria. One of the requirement was to ensure,  all the error codes and messages match the API design.I was able to induce the server to raise all the HTTP error codes specified in the API design. Only edge case was the `internal server error(i.e. 500)`. I had no means of inducing the controller to raise this error. Since, I am testing error reply and since this reply is independent of the location and source of the exception I decided to stub it.

Comment: Having the first line `...any_instance.stub...`, do you still need the second line to stub again on the `controller` variable???

Answer (score 0):

It's actually an instance variable: `@controller`.

Comment: `@controller` is nil before the request in request specs. I'd stay away from it.

Comment: Oh. Well I'm obviously going to have to defer to your expertise on that!