# Rspec: stubbing controller methods ineffective (before_filter, private)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, stub

I am failing to stub a controller method even after reading dozens of threads and blog posts, so here's my situation:

**My controller**: app/controllers/my_controller.rb

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :my_private_method, only:[:new]

  # ...

  private

  # This should be stubbed and not fire
  def my_private_method
    binding.pry
    redirect_to '/failure.html'
  end
end
```

**My spec**: spec/controllers/my_spec.rb

```
describe MyController do
  before :each do   
    controller.stub!(:my_private_method).and_return(true)
  end

  it 'should load' do
    binding.pry
    visit new_my_path
    response.status.should == 200
  end
end
```

My system:

ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-linux]

Rails 3.2.13

**Any help?**

Incidentally, I find when I use `binding.pry` to check `controller.object_id` in my `it 'should load'` block, I get a *different* object_id than when I check `self.object_id` in `my_private_method`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use a method other than `visit` in the spec. Apparently, `visit` is intended for feature specs only. Instead, use `get` or `post` etc.

Comment: That's consistent with relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs, but it doesn't explain why the `any_instance_of` approach doesn't work.

Comment: I agree entirely. Nevertheless, that was my experience.

Answer (score 2):

Your "incidental" comment is very much related to what is going on here, I think.

I believe the `controller` variable in your spec is associated with the implicit `MyController.new` that was done by RSpec when you passed `MyController` to `describe`. That instance of `MyController`, however, is different than the instance that is created by Rails when you visit `new_my_path`.

I believe you can use `MyController.any_instance.stub` to do what you want to do here.

Comment: I'm having an issue stubbing out a model method being called in a controller (Rails app). Regardless of whether I stub at the instance level or class level, the stubbed method gets called and the code in it executes when testing it. Is it likely that I too may have a similar case of two different instances? Is this a common issue when testing Rails controllers?

Comment: How can I determine this i.e. print object_id's in controller and rspec test?

Comment: You can certainly print object_ids (or just print objects, since they contain the object address, which is also unique), but if you're stubbing with `any_instance`, I don't understand why your actual code would still be called.  Frankly, I haven't done any controller testing in Rails, so I can't answer from experience regarding whether this is a common issue.

Comment: I tried `MyController.any_instance.stub` as well. It was to no better effect. Incidentally, `MyController.any_instance.stub!` (with an exclamation mark) raises `RuntimeError: stub! is not supported on any_instance. Use stub instead.`

Comment: @JellicleCat,  know it doesn't answer your question, but have you considered/tried the approach described in https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs? I'll get back to you on the original question.

Comment: Found the answer. It was not what I expected.

Comment: I see from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743306/stubbing-controller-actions-in-rspec-request-specs that stubbing controller methods with `any_instance` does work, at least in request specs. Can you share more details of your spec and the failure you're seeing?

Comment: Alas, my spec looks almost identical to what I gave in my description: I request a page (or controller action) and check the response. I actually stubbed out two other private `before_filter` functions as well, and I asserted `response.should render_template('new')`. That is the sum of it. I conjectured that my spec_helper.rb file might be causing a conflict, so I rolled it back to its first revision, but I experienced no better behaviour.