# Rspec: stub out controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, controller, stub

I'm writing request specs for one controller and I'd like to stub out another controller's method which is called via AJAX. The controller action in the AJAX call is for geolocating addresses, and its unrelated to the rest of the request. The controller action always renders nothing.

I've tried:

```
before :each
  AddressesController.any_instance.stub(:update).and_return nil
end
```

However, that gives me an error:

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 ActionView::MissingTemplate:
   Missing template addresses/update, application/update
```

No view template exists for the action, since it always renders nothing.

Is there a way I can stub out the other controller's action entirely, or do I need to stub out the internals of the method instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to stub a controller action from within a request spec. However you can stub the AJAX request, so that the controller action is never reached. [Webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) is a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743306/stubbing-controller-actions-in-rspec-request-specs) for more clarification. Like you mentioned, you should stub out the internals of the method instead.

Comment: I had seen that question before, however I don't see how it relates to my question. That question seems to be, oddly, testing Rails's handling of controller errors, for which I suppose it makes sense to stub the internals. I'm asking about stubbing an action for a separate controller, and I'd rather not have to consider the internals of this action when it has nothing to do with what I'm trying to test. Am I missing something? Is there a way to do this?